# Using a returned variable from one file in another in python

Tags: python, user-interface, import, kivy

I am using kivy to create some basic GUI for a project and have separated that into another .py file from the other code related to the program. Here is GUI.py:

```
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.rows = 3

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "Enter a name: "))

        self.name =  TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.name)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.go = Button(text = "Go!", font_size = 38)
        self.add_widget(self.go)
        self.go.bind(on_press = self.pressed)

    def pressed(self, instance):
        track_name = self.name.text
        return track_name

class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

GUI().run()
```

I want to use the track_name variable in project.py but don't know how to access it. Here is project.py:

```
import GUI
track_name = GUI.pressed()
print(track_name)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\Python Projekti\xxxx\project.py", line 8, in <module>
     track_name = GUI.pressed()
 AttributeError: module 'GUI' has no attribute 'pressed'
```

What should I change?

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example.

Comment: As the error says, your `pressed()` method in not in the `GUI` module. It is in the `MyGrid` class.

Comment: @JohnAnderson So how do I access it?

Comment: You cannot access it with the structure as you have it. When you run `project.py` the `import GUI` command will start the `GUI` `App`, because of the line `GUI().run()` in the `GUI.py` file, And the other lines in `project.py` will not run until the `GUI` `App` is stopped (the `GUI().run()` does not return until the `App` stops). It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Keep in mind that commands that are outside of classes are executed immediately, either before or after the `App` runs, but not during.

Comment: maybe if you want to use the variables, use a database or any text file or JSON file to store the value and use it after the app stops.